# Why won't my img src be read when it's a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

How come in the `Photos` component, the `src` attribute takes in my URL and displays the image successfully on this line `<img src={localStorage.getItem("img")} alt="photo"/>`.

But it won't display in the `<Grid/>` component (the line below the aforementioned line).  I can't spot what I'm doing wrong as on both instances, the `src` attribute's being populated which's responsible for displaying the image.

What am I doing wrong?

`Photos` Component:

```
<img src={localStorage.getItem("img")} alt="photo"/>
{ (filePreview && chosenImage && localStorage.getItem('token')) ? <Grid imgSrc={localStorage.getItem("img")} userName={localStorage.getItem('name')}/> : <h1>no photos</h1> }
```

`Grid` Component:

```
const [userImg, setImgState] = useState(props);
<img src={userImg.imgSrc} onDoubleClick={() => setCount(count + 1)} alt="userImage" className="gallery-img"/>
```

Comment: setting state this way is a bit of an anti-pattern and won't update if the props change unless you explicitly change it (useEffect is helpful here)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm assuming correct, `props` is an `Object` that is passed into the component. You can try the following:

```js
const [userImg, setUserImg] = useState(props.imgSrc);
return <img src={userImg} />
```

Or, it might be that imgSrc isn't passed into the props at component initialization. If that's the case, use `props` directly into the `img` source, and propagate updates backwards.

```js
return <img src={props.userImg} />
```

Comment: You could also suggest watching for changes in props in a useEffect to update state: `useEffect(() => { setUserImg(props.imgSrc) }, [props.imgSrc]);`

Comment: But won't that be the same as using props directly, but just more overhead?@pilchard

Comment: That depends, as I said in my comment above it is somewhat of an anti pattern to set state with props or at least an indication that you should be lifting state up and managing it in the parent, but there are many legitimate uses of the pattern – a lot of custom hooks accept initial values as props and then manage the state lifecycle internally (often watching for changes to props as I mentioned in my suggestion).